# How in JS to group subarrays by common elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of subarrays. Each subarray has at least one element which is duplicated at least in one more subarray. For example:

```
[
    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
    ['ddd', 'aaa'],
    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'eee'],
    ['kkk', 'mmm', 'nnn'],
    ['mmm', 'ooo']
]
```

In this case 'ddd' and 'eee' are not duplicated anywhere, but another elements in the same subarrays are duplicated at least in one more subarray. I need to group elements in new subarrays to receive the following output:

```
[
    ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee'],
    ['kkk', 'mmm', 'nnn', 'ooo']
]
```

In other words, I need to group "friends". So if 'ddd' is a "friend" somewhere for 'aaa' and if 'eee' is a friend somewhere for 'bbb' and 'aaa' and 'bbb' also are friends, we group them all in one new subarray. But 'mmm' is not a friend for 'aaa', 'bbb' etc. but is a friend for kkk and nnn and ooo, so group them in another subarray

Comment: you mean duplicate element in one array and unique in another ?

Comment: I dont understand why your expected output is 2 different arrays? What is the second array meant for?

Comment: @Kevin.a see the last paragraph in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could first use `reduce` and `Set` to get an array of unique values and then `map` it to array of arrays with unique values.

```js
const data = [
  ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
  ['ddd', 'aaa'],
  ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'eee'],
  ['kkk', 'mmm', 'nnn'],
  ['mmm', 'ooo']
]

const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  const match = r.find(a => e.some(s => a.has(s)))
  if (!match) r.push(new Set(e));
  else e.forEach(el => match.add(el))
  return r
}, []).map(e => Array.from(e))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Set and reduce

- Loop over the array, use join current value to use it as key
- Check if any of element from current array is already present on op or not
- If already present add the current array to existing Set else set to a new key with value as current array as Set

```js
let data = [['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],['ddd', 'aaa'], ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'eee'],['kkk', 'mmm', 'nnn'],['mmm', 'ooo']]

let final = data.reduce((op, inp) => {
  let key = inp.join(',')
  let included = Object.keys(op)
  let found = included.find(v => inp.some(curr => v.includes(curr)))
  if (found) {
    op[found] = new Set([...op[found], ...inp])
  } else {
    op[key] = new Set(inp)
  }
  return op
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(final).map(v => [...v]))
```

Answer (score 1):

A different solution, where the order does not matter.

> Beside the given solutions, and the lack of joining groups with items who build a temporary group first and the an array of items belongs to two groups, like
>
> ```
> var data = [
>         ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], // group aaa, bbb, ccc
>         // ...
>         ['x', 'y'],            // creates own group x, y
>         ['x', 'aaa']           // fails here to join x, y with aaa, ...
>     ],
> ```
>
> with this data a check is made and groups are joined to a single group as well as their items.

This solution takes a hash table with the items as keys and an object which contains a single property with a `Set`.

```
{ s: new Set }
```

This is necessary to use the object refernece for the same group and the reference of the set for the same group, but not for items who are not in the actual array.

If later a property of the hahs table is found and it is not equal to actual group, or the set not equal to the group's set, then all items get the same set and all hashes of the group are reassigned to the group set.

At the end, the values are taken from the hash table, onle the set property is used for getting unique sets and the sets are converted to a arrays.

Voilà.

```js
var data = [['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'aaa'], ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'eee'], ['kkk', 'mmm', 'nnn'], ['mmm', 'ooo'],['x', 'y'], ['x', 'aaa']],
    hash = data.reduce((r, a) => {
        var common = { s: new Set };
        a.forEach(v => {
            common.s.add(v);
            if (!r[v]) return r[v] = common;
            if (r[v] === common || r[v].s === common.s) return;
            common.s.forEach(k => {
                r[k].s = r[v].s;
                r[v].s.add(k);
            });
            common.s = r[v].s;
        });
        return r;
    }, {}),
    grouped = Array
        .from(new Set(Object.values(hash).map(({ s }) => s)))
        .map(s => Array.from(s));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A different approach by using onyl an array of sets and by filtering the array for found items or adding the values of an array into a new set.

```js
function getGroups(array) {
    var groups = [],
        once;

    do {
        once = false;
        array = array.filter(a => {
            var temp;
            if (a.some(v => temp = groups.find(s => s.has(v)))) {
                a.forEach(Set.prototype.add, temp);
                return false;
            }
            if (once) return true;
            groups.push(new Set(a));
            once = true;
        });
    } while (array.length);
    return groups.map(s => Array.from(s));
}

var data = [['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], ['ddd', 'aaa'], ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'eee'], ['kkk', 'mmm', 'nnn'], ['mmm', 'ooo'], ['x', 'y'], ['x', 'aaa']],
    result = getGroups(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```